# ASP.Net 6.0 Migrations Entity Framework error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ddd

estoy realizando un sistema de APIS en ASP.Net 6.0 y usando .Net Core 6.0 con entity framework para la creacion de modelos en la base de datos...
Al intentar hacer las migraciones me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Unable to create an object of type 'RtvcContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Para aclarar, ese link que me dice en el error ya lo visite, y copie y pegue el codigo tal cual dice, les dejo el codigo de mi proyecto:

Mi clase Program:

```
using RtvcApi;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

Mi clase Startup

```
using Infrastructure.EntityFramework;
namespace RtvcApi;

public class Startup
{
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
        //services.AddDbContext<RtvcContext>();
        services.AddApplicationServices();
        services.AddInfrastructureServices(configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    }
}
```

Mis clases de configuracion:
AddApplicationServices

```
namespace RtvcApi;

public static class ApplicationServiceRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection Services) 
    {
        Services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        Services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //AGREGAMOS POR INYECCION DE DEPENDENCIAS LAS VALIDACIONES DEL BEHAVIOUR
        Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UnhandledExceptionBehaviour<,>));
        Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehaviour<,>));

        return Services;
    }

}
```

AddInfrastructureServices:

```
namespace Infrastructure.EntityFramework;
public static class InfrastructureServiceRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configurations)
    {
        String ConnectionString = configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<RtvcContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseMySql(
                ConnectionString,
                ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString)
            );
        });

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(IRepositoryBase<>));
        services.AddScoped<IEntityRepository, MySQLEntityRepository>();

        services.Configure<EmailSetting>(c => configurations.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
        services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

Ahora en la capa de Infraestructura , que es donde tengo el contexto con las configuraciones, el codigo es el siguiente:

RtvcContext

```
namespace Infrastructure.EntityFramework;
public class RtvcContext : DbContext
{
    public RtvcContext(DbContextOptions<RtvcContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<RtvcEntity> Entitys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntityType> EntitysTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //ENTITYS
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EntityConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EntityTypeConfiguration());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder.Properties<decimal>()
            .HavePrecision(22, 2);

        configurationBuilder.Properties<string>()
        .HaveColumnType("varchar(255)");
    }
```

}

EntityConfiguration

```
namespace Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Configurations;
public class EntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Entity> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("entidades");

        modelBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder.Property(x => x.EntityTypeId).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(0).HasColumnName("entidadTipoId");
        modelBuilder.HasIndex(x => x.EntityTypeId);

        modelBuilder.Property(x => x.CreatedAt).HasColumnName("FechaActualizado").HasDefaultValue(DateTime.MinValue);
        modelBuilder.Property(x => x.UpdateAt).HasColumnName("FechaActualizado").HasDefaultValue(DateTime.MinValue);

        modelBuilder.Property(x => x.Email).HasColumnName("correoElectronico").HasDefaultValue("");
        modelBuilder.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("correoElectronico").HasDefaultValue("");
        modelBuilder.Property(x => x.LastName).HasColumnName("correoElectronico").HasDefaultValue("");
        modelBuilder.Property(x => x.NumberPhone).HasColumnName("correoElectronico").HasDefaultValue("");
    }
}
```

EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
namespace Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Configurations;
public class EntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Entity> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("entidades_tipos");

        modelBuilder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        modelBuilder.Property(e => e.Name).HasDefaultValue("").HasColumnName("Nombre");
    }
}
```

Tambien agregue  la clase databasecontextoptions , el codigo es el siguiente:

DataBaseContextOptions.cs:

```
   public class DataBaseContextOptions : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<RtvcContext>
    {
        public RtvcContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
    
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RtvcContext>();
            String ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            builder.UseMySql(
                ConnectionString,
                 ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString));
    
            return new RtvcContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Espero haber sido claro y que alguien pueda ayudarme con esto porque no se me ocurre que puede ser, gracias!

Error mas especifico:

```
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'RtvcContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'RtvcContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Infrastructure.EntityFramework.RtvcContext]' while attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.EntityFramework.RtvcContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

Imagen de la estructura de mi proyecto:
[image: descripcion proyecto]

appsettings.json:
[image: appsettings.json imagen]

Comment: Agrega el comando que estás utilizando para generar las migraciones.

Comment: @fredyfx estoy utilizando dotnet ef migrations add Initial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta ejecutar:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration -v --context RtvcContext
```

Ese `-v` te dará mayores detalles en la consola, muy útil para realizar debugging.

Actualización:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration -s RTVCAPI -p ..\Src\Infrastructure\Infrastructure -v --context RtvcContext
```

Luego de ver cómo está el proyecto, este comando debería funcionar, asegúrate de tener las rutas bien definidas, utiliza `tab` para seleccionar el proyecto luego de colocar el `-s` y nuevamente utiliza `tab` para seleccionar el proyecto de infrastructure. En caso no aparezca, navega con `.\Src\ProyectoAqui` o con `..\`

El `-s` quiere decir "Obtén los settings de este proyecto".

El `-p` quiere decir "Aplica a este proyecto".

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta porque no me deja ponerlo aca en los comentarios porque es muy largo

Comment: ahi edite el error en la pregunta asi se puede apreciar mejor, me tira eso.. tenes idea que puede ser?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega la organización de la solución de visual studio, donde se pueda ver cómo tienes todos los proyectos. Por otro lado, ¿Por qué está vacío el `Configure` en el `startup.cs` ? Y también agrega lo que tienes en `appsettings.json` eso sí, oculta cualquier usuario y contraseña reemplazando caracteres como `user=****** password=XXXXXX`

Comment: Ahi esta Fredy, ya subi la edicion con el appsettings.json, con la estructura del proyecto y tambien con la nueva clase que agregue que es DataBaseContextOptions.cs con su respectivo codigo, el tema del startup esta vacio porque todavia no arranque a desarrollar esa parte, queria primero iniciar con las migraciones, gracias por la ayuda, espero que me logres ayudar a resolver esto! (:

Comment: Dale hermano, acabo de actualizar la respuesta, creo que con eso ya puedes avanzar. Al menos encontraremos algo diferente, en caso el EF te diga que necesita "Design", instala el nuget package en la API y santo remedio.

Comment: Gracias !!!! Me funciono, puse asi:

dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s RtvcApi -p Infrastructure  -v --context RtvcContext

Comment: Sos un genio jaja gracias !!

Comment: un gusto colaborar, sigue desarrollando hermano, éxitos con Clean Architecture :D